# Pass UserID Parameter in Foreach Loop with Popover Content

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, foreach, parameter-passing

[Here is a picture how it lists all phone numbers from all users when I hover over the user account.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwU3O.png)

I am creating an MVC project using ASP.NET and using Razor to queue all the users by "@foreach (var item in Model)". In that table, I want to use a popover that will display the user's phone numbers once hovered over the name of the account (called Dealer). It currently lists all the phones on record from all users but I want it to be specific to that user. I tried using ActionLinks (how I passed the same parameter for Edit, Details, and Delete) as well as  tags but neither seem to work. How can I pass the UserID parameter to limit the popover to listing only the phone numbers linked to a specific user?

Here is the code for the table:

```
<table>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Dealer)
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="#" data-toggle="popover" title="Phones">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserName)</a>
            <div id="phone-content" style="display: none">
                @foreach (var phone in Model)
                {
                    //Using ActionLinks
                    @Html.ActionLink("Mobile", "ListPhones", new { id = item.Id })<br />
                    @Html.ActionLink("Business", "ListPhones", new { id = item.Id })<br />
                    @Html.ActionLink("Fax", "ListPhones", new { id = item.Id })<br>

                    //Using <a href> tags
                    <a href="tel:@phone.PhoneMobile">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => phone.PhoneMobile)</a><br />
                    <a href="tel:@phone.PhoneBus">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => phone.PhoneBus)</a><br />
                    <a href="tel:@phone.PhoneFax">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => phone.PhoneFax)</a><br />
                }
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id })<br />
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.Id })<br />
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Id })
        </td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
```

In the controller, I created a new class to list the phone information and tried passing the parameter there.
Here is the code for editing a user in the controller which passes the parameter correctly:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(string id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(id);
        if (user == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        var userRoles = await UserManager.GetRolesAsync(user.Id);

        return View(new AdminEditUserViewModel()
        {
            Id = user.Id,
            Dealer = user.Dealer,
            UserName = user.UserName,
            FirstName = user.FirstName,
            LastName = user.LastName,
            Address = user.Address,
            City = user.City,
            State = user.State,
            Zip = user.Zip,
            Email = user.Email,
            PhoneMobile = user.PhoneMobile,
            PhoneBus = user.PhoneBus,
            PhoneExt = user.PhoneExt,
            PhoneFax = user.PhoneFax,
            RolesList = RoleManager.Roles.ToList().Select(x => new SelectListItem()
            {
                Selected = userRoles.Contains(x.Name),
                Text = x.Name,
                Value = x.Name
            })
        });
    }

    //
    // POST: /Users/Edit/5
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Edit([Bind(Include = "Dealer,UserName,FirstName,LastName,Address,City,State,Zip,Email,PhoneMobile,PhoneFax,PhoneBus,PhoneExt,Id")]
    AdminEditUserViewModel editUser, params string[] selectedRole)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(editUser.Id);
            if (user == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }

            user.Dealer = editUser.Dealer;
            user.UserName = editUser.UserName;
            user.FirstName = editUser.FirstName;
            user.LastName = editUser.LastName;
            user.Address = editUser.Address;
            user.City = editUser.City;
            user.State = editUser.State;
            user.Zip = editUser.Zip;
            user.Email = editUser.Email;
            user.PhoneMobile = editUser.PhoneMobile;
            user.PhoneBus = editUser.PhoneBus;
            user.PhoneExt = editUser.PhoneExt;
            user.PhoneFax = editUser.PhoneFax;

            var userRoles = await UserManager.GetRolesAsync(user.Id);

            selectedRole = selectedRole ?? new string[] { };

            var result = await UserManager.AddToRolesAsync(user.Id, selectedRole.Except(userRoles).ToArray<string>());

            if (!result.Succeeded)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", result.Errors.First());
                return View();
            }
            result = await UserManager.RemoveFromRolesAsync(user.Id, userRoles.Except(selectedRole).ToArray<string>());

            if (!result.Succeeded)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", result.Errors.First());
                return View();
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Something failed.");
        return View();
    }
```

Versus the code for listing the phones in the controller:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> ListPhones(string id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(id);
        if (user == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        return View(new AdminEditUserViewModel()
        {
            Id = user.Id,
            PhoneMobile = user.PhoneMobile,
            PhoneBus = user.PhoneBus,
            PhoneExt = user.PhoneExt,
            PhoneFax = user.PhoneFax
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom action and try something like:

```
 <a href="/GetPhoneInfo/@item.Id" data-toggle="popover" title="Phones">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserName)</a>
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. The problem though is that I believe the href should be # so that the popover can be clicked without redirecting to the new page. The way it needs to be set up is you can hover over a user to see all the phones linked to the user, but you then click on the user to make it stay and therefore click on one of the numbers. I tried playing around with your suggestion but from what I understand, that will always redirect to that page rather than opening up the popover.

Answer (score 0):

As usual, you should read the [docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers). I'm assuming you're using Bootstrap because it *looks* like Bootstrap and Bootstrap is employed by MVC by default. For future reference, though, you should be explicit about things like that, and you should probably tag your question that way as well.

That said, the docs tell you everything you need to know. You have to specify the trigger(s) that will activate the popover, and luckily for you, Bootstrap's popover does allow multiple triggers. For your scenario, you'll want to use both `hover` and `focus`. The `focus` trigger opens the popover on click and then keeps it open until it loses focus, which seems like exactly what you want.

Basically, you just need to take their provided code for a "dismissable" popover and add the additional `hover` trigger:

```
<a tabindex="0" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" role="button" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus hover" title="Dismissible popover" data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. Right?">Dismissible popover</a>
```

Then, of course, just customize the content/classes to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

[image: demo]

i was able to make it work.send me your email for the sample project.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! My email is maxxtreme.inc@gmail.com.